# phpexcel border using parameter

Tags: netbeans, phpexcel

```html
if (!empty($c_date)){
 //Border
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:'($start_out.$end))->applyFromArray(
       array(
 'borders' => array(
     'allborders' => array(
       'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
       )
     ),  
      )
    );
    }
```

i don't know where is the mistake here, please advice me to correct it.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:'($start_out.$end))
```

looks like it should give a syntax error

(Assuming that `$start_out` is a column address and `$end` is a row number) try

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:' . $start_out . $end)
```